# Migration To Ask Different - specific question

Tags: support, migration

My question results from the question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355076/how-do-i-change-the-services-sub-component-to-not-use-safari-web-browser) which has a [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356231/237) saying that this has been [asked and answered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935301/how-to-force-mac-os-to-open-search-with-google-in-chrome).

OK all normal and a common occurence.

However in this case the question is closed on Stack Overflow as being off topic (I think correctly). Given this can we get that question migrated to here where it is on topic and would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is probably no, as a moderator here, we cannot migrate a question that has aged past 60 days. Also, we can’t pull questions, so they (SO Moderators and users) would have to send it over, assuming they both can and wish to.

- [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

The exception for employees migrating seems to be not something they entertain requests and only do it in extenuating circumstances when they need to move something as opposed when we want to see it moved.

What we can do is be sure that (if needed, a new question gets asked here and) the contents of that other answer get replicated here (giving credit / attribution of course) so that no matter what happens in terms of deletion and closure on the other site, we have an on topic question with a correct answer.

You are correct in the general case, we would prefer to migrate if we could, but I believe we cannot accomplish that even if we wanted to in this specific case.

Comment: Yes I  thought so. But note the linked question does not deal really with the case where the original is closed.

Comment: @Mark Then we'll need to just craft the correct answer for the question asked or ask the question that gets the answer provided. Actually both is just fine. Even if we have 5 to 10 versions of the same question - we can always link them later with closes so that all the searching of different phrasing gets to the same good answer.